# Select Drawable file in Android through a menu

Tags: android, drawable

How to select a file drawable, that I have in my project,, through three buttons from the main page and this should change another screen of another activity, or if it could be easier i would like to change the names of the files that are inside the drawable folder.(sorry about my bad english).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in `@drawable` you have picture and want to set it in to the ImageView you can call: `android:src="@drawable/common_signin_btn_icon_dark" />`

Is this what you need?

If you want to change page view, the best way is to use [fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

**EDIT**
Make array in folder values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="images">
        <item>@drawable/p1</item>
        <item>@drawable/p2</item>
  </array>
</resources>
```

In JAVA:

```
TypedArray imageMain;

Resources res = this.getResources();
imageMain = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.images);
```

Make if/switch/while and calll inside

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.imageView1);
image.setImageResource(imageMain.getResourceId(position, -1));
```

Where position is number of picture from array

Comment: i would like that this line in one xml:
 android:background="@drawable/fondo"
would change for these others:
if you choose first button it would be like this:
 android:background="@drawable/fondo1"
if you choose second button it would be like this:
 android:background="@drawable/fondo2"
if you choose third button it would be like this:
 android:background="@drawable/fondo3"

Comment: thanks a lot, i think that this is the good answer but i'm not ready to solve this problem by myself, thanks a lot for your time and sorry for been the guilty of this "wasted time".... :(

Comment: I am using this same code in my app right now, so should work :) You are welcome

Comment: i don't doubt if you have used this code in your app, but i should apply your code in my own, but, my problem is diferent because, i want to change one image in another activity, not in the same activity where i choose the picture, i mean i choose the "wallpaper picture" in the "options menu" and i have to change in the "game screen", not in the "options menu", can you understand what is what i want? thanks a lot again.

Comment: you can do this same but instead of array you can simply make: `ImageView image = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(
                R.id.imageView1);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxxxxxxxxx);`

Comment: i can't understand your explanation...
i'm going to explain the problem better (if i could...)
i have one activity called options, inside of it there are three buttons and this buttons have one image, and i want that the image that the user choose it would appear when the user open another different activity called "game", it will appear the image that has chosen before as the background of the game

Comment: Just copy code from my comment and place in every action button. it's simple method to replace image. This is for picture in ImageView.

Comment: once again, sorry i can't understand your answer.... 
i don't want to change the image of every button, because i know how can i do it it's very easy: android:background="@drawable/fondo1"
i want that the user choose between those buttons which image would be in another different activity so, if i copy your code the image of the button will change, and i don't want to do that.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Sorry. By my answer you can change image `ImageView`,  not button background. So if you want to start new activity and change picture you can use my method in every activity for example in OnCreate method. [Look at here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imageview-example/)

Comment: yes you have almost understood me, this is almost the solution!!, 
i only want the same example, but i wold like to "share" the picture between others activities, not only in the same activity that i have chosen the image. (thanks for your time).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the class `BitmapDrawable` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html)

It provides the constructor: `BitmapDrawable(Resources res, InputStream is)`

You can use that to read a file from your `assets`, or `raw` folder. Hopefully this should help.